# Rack middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Нужно перехватить html и отправить его в php скрипт для модификации(подмены данных). Написан middleware, как в методе call получить весь html страницы?

```
class Foo
 def initialize(app)
    @app = app
 end

 def call(env)
    [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, ["Hello Rack Participants from across the globe"]]
 end

end
```

Comment: Вы же не сами написали этот код, верно?

Comment: Уже сделал) если кому будет интересно могу рассказать

Comment: Отвечать на собственные вопросы тут нормальное явление :)

Comment: Все нормально))

Comment: Не знаю, чей минус, но я б на ваш ответ посмотрел. И, возможно, поправил.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'open3'

class SeoShield
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    status, headers, response = @app.call(env)

    html = syscall('php -f index.php ' + [response.body].to_s)
    html = html[0].gsub('\n','')

    seo_html = ''
    response.each { |part| seo_html = html }
    [status, headers, [seo_html]]
  end

  def syscall(*cmd)
    begin
        stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(*cmd)
    rescue
    end
  end

end
```